Metamask - How to claim ownership of Unknown account
I tried to transfer a small amount of ETH from my Binance Web3 wallet to my Metamask wallet using the OPMainnet.
Now, the transfer is successful, and has left my BinanceWeb3 wallet and shows successfully transferred.
But where did it transfer? It hasnt arrived on my MetaMask wallet.
Infact it shows on a OPMainnet address that I did not enter, it had selected the recipients address automatically.
How is this possible?
Now when I enabled the OPMainnet network on my Metamask, it shows the balance as available but the account status is "Unowned"
How do i OWN this account now to avail my ETH????
Pls help

The wallets are just applications. It's about the key/address pair.. You can't bridge between chains by directly sending between addresses need to use a bridge, or it will just be sent to the address on the source chain. Unless someone else has your key, you must have input the address via some method. If share the address and hash will take a look.

Hey Maka, thank you so much for the response.  Highly appreciated.
Where can I share the requested details - via email?
Pls share your email address.

Moreover, when I selected OP Mainnet, it did not ask me for any address to send it to.  As I clicked next, I assumed it would now ask me, but instead of asking me, it already sent it to an address of its own.
Now in my metamask list, when I enabled to show me the OPMainnet also, the funds are reflecting there, but I am not able to own it to transfer to my actual Ehter address.

No you should here, to be safe, and make sure not to share anything sensitive. Don't post the key. Just add the public wallet address or the transaction hash.

Trxn Hash
0x72887d548130f3ea1518dd588997b4c913f05338f9c9a9ef75e1ba8b80be7979

Did you enabled Optimism network in Metamask?

From address is Binance, and it is a direct transfer of eth, a withdraw from the exchange essentially. Where did you get the address from if it isn't yours? When you say when I enabled the OPMainnet network on my Metamask, it shows the balance as available but the account status is "Unowned". Does it show the address the where the eth is 0x222ff3..., under the account name at the top of the wallet application, or does it show a different address?

Where did you get the address from if it isn't yours?
I did not generate this address at all.  In fact before the Binance transfer I did not even have any such OPMiannet address. It generated this address automatically without asking me.
Yes it shows this 0x222ff3 address in my metamask wallet under the OPMainnet network, and its UNOWNED, so I am not able to withdraw from it.
